# Sorting a Unix environment in C

Tags: c

I tried sorting my environment.

My C++ version (the std::sort line along with the CstrLess class) works, but the qsort version fails. What am  I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
extern char** environ;


struct CstrLess{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2){ return ::strcmp(s1,s2)<0; }
};

int main(){
  char** env = environ;
  size_t sz = 0;
  for(;*env; env++,sz++) {;} //measure the env

  //?
  qsort(environ, sz, sizeof(char*), (int (*)(const void*, const void*)) strcmp);

  /*std::sort(environ, environ + sz, CstrLess{});*/

  env = environ;
  while(*env){
    printf("%s%c", *env++, '\0');
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: `qsort` pass `char**` to `strcmp`, not `char*`.

Comment: @ecatmur The output isn't sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qsort` passes its comparison function *pointers* to the elements to be compared; you need to indirect that pointer to get the `char const*` pointers to be passed to `strcmp`:

```
qsort(environ, sz, sizeof(char*),
    [](const void* a, const void* b) {
        return strcmp(
            *reinterpret_cast<const char**>(a), *reinterpret_cast<const char**>(b)); });
```

Pure C solution:

```
int qsort_strcmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return strcmp(*(const char**)(a), *(const char**)(b));
}

// ...

  qsort(environ, sz, sizeof(char*), qsort_strcmp);
```

Comment: Why the cast to `const char**` btw? Seems entirely superfluous.

Comment: @Lundin the pointer has to be indirected, as well as cast. You can't indirect a `const void *`, as that would yield a `const void` lvalue, which can't exist.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to `strcmp` is of type `int(*)(const char *, const char *)`.

The type expected by `qsort` is `int(*)(const void*, const void*)`.

Wild function pointer conversions is undefined behavior. Your compiler would rightfully have given you a warning/error if you hadn't silenced it with the ugly cast. It is possible that there could be different calling conventions for the different types, so this undefined behavior is a valid concern.

The correct approach is to write a wrapper function and pass a pointer to that instead:

```
int strcmp_wrapper (const void* s1, const void* s2)
{
  return strcmp(s1, s2); // implicit conversion from const void* to const char*.
}
```